# Codegen generation with Serializable Implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, codegen

I'am generating a spring boot gradle project using codegen but I want the model classes to implement Serializable how can do that?

I saw that we can add "serializableModel" : true in config.yml but where exactly should I add it?

I tried add "serializableModel" : true in
options:
commonLib:
useResponseWrapper:false
serializableModel:true

But didn't work, instead it only generated a tests folder in the project.